# Package manager NPM and node.js Integrity

Tags: node.js, open-source, package, npm

I have just created a new package on NPM (which was surprisingly easy) and I am interested in how the integrity of packages is maintained. Can anybody publish a new version of a package, or is this restricted to just my user account?

If anyone can publish changes to a package, how can their modifications be monitored to ensure that the project will still work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage multiple owners for an NPM package:

```
npm owner add username packagename
npm owner rm username packagename
npm owner ls packagename
```

Ideally the project should be managed by the group in a code repository like github, then any user can update the package from the repo. So long as the version numbers are incremented accordingly it should be easy to follow. NPM should disallow updates for the same version number.

Answer (score 1):

Since each package has an author I am pretty sure only the author can update the packages he owns. You can find the structure of packages over here: http://isaacs.iriscouch.com/_utils/database.html?registry